# Attempt to write to field 'android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, android-camera2

I use `Camera2` to implementation camera preview for devices with API > 20. I got the error on asus_t00j with android 5.0.0. I am not sure why it appear.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.mRemoteDevice' on a null object reference
   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.close(CameraDeviceImpl.java:773)
   at com.vyda.stream.screencast.CameraHelper.closeCamera(CameraHelper.java:410)
   at com.vyda.stream.screencast.CameraHelper.stopCameraAndRemoveWindow(CameraHelper.java:150)
   at com.vyda.stream.screencast.ScreencastService.endScreencasting(ScreencastService.java:307)
   at com.vyda.stream.screencast.ScreencastService$8.onClick(ScreencastService.java:275)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

CameraHelper::closeCamera()

```
private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            cameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            if (null != captureSession) {
                captureSession.close();
                captureSession = null;
            }
            if (null != cameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice.close();
                cameraDevice = null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
        } finally {
            cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }
```

Comment: cameraDevice is obviously null when you're calling close() on it.

Comment: I cannot call close for cameraDevice if it is null.

Answer (score 3):

`captureSession.close()` is asynchronous, which means that when your code arrives to `cameraDevice.close()`, the underlying camera object (but not the `cameraDevice` member of you **CameraHelper**) is destroyed. With both `captureSession.close()` and `cameraDevice.close()` you are supposed to wait for the [`onClosed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback.html#onClosed(android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice)) callback.

But the description of [`cameraDevice.close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#close()) explains that the active session will be closed for you, so you don't need the `captureSession.close()` call in your scenario.

PS I believe that what you experience is a buggy implementation of Camera2 API on ASUS device.

Comment: Thx for you answer. Sounds well but i have to check it. I will let you know about my progress :)